# How to use certain network interface cards for certain tasks

Tags: networking, windows-10, wireless-networking, ethernet

On my computer I have access to two different networks.

The main one (through the wireless NIC) is the one I need to be on 90% of the time. However I also have a USB to ethernet adapter that connects to a separate test network that I need to be on for a Remote Desktop Connection to work.

However, I have found that when I connect my USB to Ethernet adapter, Windows defaults to this (as expected) but then I am unable to do 90% of my tasks that requires the IP address of the Wireless NIC.

So my question is. How is it possible for Windows to use the Ethernet network when I a Remote Desktop Connection and use my Wi-Fi for the rest?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried editing the host routing table? You may be able to direct **destination** specific traffic that way. I.e VPN.mywork.com to the gateway address that corresponds to the work ISP connection.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any way to do this **per program**, but if you know ahead of time the IP you'll be connecting to with Remote Desktop you can do it by modifying the routing table:

Open an Admin PowerShell (Win+X, Windows PowerShell (Admin))

First, you need to find the index of the interface you want to use for Remote Desktop:

```
Get-NetIPAddress | Select IPAddress,InterfaceAlias,InterfaceIndex
```

This should return something like the following:

```
IPAddress                               InterfaceAlias                 InterfaceIndex
---------                               --------------                 --------------
ffff::ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff               Local Area Connection* 3                   15
::1                                     Loopback Pseudo-Interface 1                 1
ffff::ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff               Wi-Fi                                       9
10.0.5.203                              Local Area Connection* 3                   15
10.0.0.42                               Wi-Fi                                       9
```

If `Local Area Connection* 3` is the interface you want to use, you'll need to note the interface index (15, in this case).

Next, we need to update the routing table, so there are a few important points:

- First is whether the RDP server you're connecting to is on the local network or not. If it is, and you don't need to go through a router to get there, you'll use `0.0.0.0` for the NextHop. If you do need to go through a router, you'll put the IP address of the router there instead.
- Next is how you specify the IP address. If it's just one IP, it'll be `<ip address>/32`. If it's a range, you'll need to modify the netmask (the `/32` part). If you need something fancier you'll need to read up on how netmasks work to make sure you can calculate an appropriate one for your use case.
- The InterfaceIndex you should have from the previous command
- And, finally, the `PolicyStore` decides whether you want this to be persistent across reboots or not. If you set it to `ActiveStore`, the change will disappear the next time you reboot (probably a good idea when you're first testing this). If you want to make it permanent, just remove that option (`-PolicyStore` and `ActiveStore`)

Putting it all together, you should get something like this:

```
New-NetRoute -InterfaceIndex 15 -DestinationPrefix 10.0.0.129/32 -NextHop 0.0.0.0 -RouteMetric 0 -PolicyStore ActiveStore
```

There's a ton of detail about routing that I had to skip over here, but this should hopefully at least get you to where you need to be pretty quickly.